# TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create engine()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery, airflow

I installed latest apache-airflow(1.9.0) with celery(4.1.0)executor.

Here is my settings from airflow.cfg:

```
broker_url = sqla+mysql://username:password@host:3306/dbname
```

Taken from http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql.

Tried to run airflow worker got

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine. Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

Note that I did not send any explicit arguments to create engine().

[This is the screenshot of my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmvdJ.png)
Any help from experts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide the full trace of the error rather than just the line you think is the error?

Comment: Please see my edit if that helps. I could not provide full stack trace as I am using remote machine which is fully restricted to expose outside world.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in Airflow 1.9.0 which has been fixed in:

- https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2842
- https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2867

There is an upcoming Airflow 1.10 release coming up which has these fixes.  If you can wait for that, use that.

If you must stick with Airflow 1.9.0, then
try switching your broker_url to use a Redis database
instead of a sqla+mysql scheme

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.

You can see that `visibility_timeout` is a default option passed to the Celery broker [as defined here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/32c5f445e450f63fa488973e221100512c32ca1b/airflow/config_templates/default_celery.py#L31).

My guess is that this option is being sent to the SQLAlchemy broker by Celery, after being [forwarded by Airflow in the app constructor](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/32c5f445e450f63fa488973e221100512c32ca1b/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py#L50), but I'm not entirely sure. I couldn't trace back all the way because you didn't provide the stack trace.

Comment: I have added(edited original post) screenshot that contains the full stack trace. Please take a look!

Comment: @SujithKumarA Please, don't do that with screen captures. Copy and paste the text so it can be searched and prevent future readers from depending on a dead link to understand the question.

Comment: Sorry @villasv. But I have no other option rather than posting the screen capture. I am working on a remote machine which does not allow me to copy any code. So ended up posting the screen capture.